# MongoDB Combine data from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to combine 3 collections into one

the first collection is make up of vehicles

```
Vehicle
{
    "_id" : ,
    "vehicle_id" : ,
    "engine_id" : ,
    "service_schedule_id" : 
}
```

The other two are service schedules and parts

```
Service_Schedule
{
    "service_schedule_id" : ,
    "date" : ,
    "description" :
}


Parts
{
    "part_id" : ,
    "vehicle_id" : ,
    "description" :, 
    "name" : 
}
```

What I want is to combine them all so in the end I have one collection that instead of having the id's contains the actual information from the collection

```
Vehicle_Complete
{
    "_id" : ,
    "vehicle_id" : ,
    "engine_id" : ,
    "service_schedule" : 
        {
           "service_schedule_id" : ,
           "date" : ,
           "description" :,
           "parts" : 
         },
    "parts" : 
     [
        {
           "part_id" : ,
           "description" :, 
           "name" : 
         }
      ]
}
```

I've seen some similar questions that use mapreduce but nothing so far has worked for me.

Comment: I don't see the need for map/reduce - why not just iterate over each in turn, inserting `Vehicle` documents, then updating with appropriate `Service_Schedule` and `Parts` info.

Comment: Yes you are right this is a better option than map reduce. I initially wanted to avoided creating intermediate C# classes for service_schedule and parts, but I can see now that doesn't make much sense. Thanks for the suggestion!